# Is the use of the singular “they” formal English or not?

Tags: formality, writing, singular-they

I have to write an academic essay for school, and I was wondering if the use of the singular “they/them/their” would be accepted.

Which of these would be “formal” and “accepted” by teachers.

- A) Someone forgot their hat. Make sure to give it back to them. (Singular they)
- B) Someone forgot his hat. Make sure to give it back to him. (Universal “he”)
- C) Someone forgot his or her hat. Make sure to give it back to him or her. (Use of both pronouns).

I am looking for the FORMAL way, since I am writing for school and shall write in a formal way!

Comment: A few minutes of searching through this site will lead you to a number of already existing questions and answers that deal with this matter. Note, however, that nothing that you will find on this site can tell you what **your** teachers regard as sufficiently formal; to find that out, you have to ask them.

Comment: All three examples violate basic English principles, as "give him/them back" is just wrong.

Comment: All your examples should use **it** because it applies to the *hat*, not the person. "They" and "them" are used as singular personal pronouns to replace him, her, he, she. For that, it would be "give it back **to them**.

Comment: Please don't change the question. SE is not a "live" tutorial site.

Comment: Ok! Sorry I am new in this site! Besides, thank you for the information! Since I am not a native speaker, it is sometimes hard to find the right info :)

Comment: A hat was forgotten.  It must be returned to its owner.

Comment: Jim's good suggestion side-steps the issue. **They** and **them** have become quite acceptable (maybe not to your teacher) to use as personal pronouns in the singular, but **it** isn't yet being replaced by **they** and **them**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I’ll ask my teacher if she’s okay with the singular they, but if not, I’ll use that alternative!

Comment: But don't forget that only your teacher and her students speak like that. If you need to speak English with natives, you'll see that opinions vary, but spoken practice is to use singular _they_ when gender is not clear. Most English speakers don't even think they do it because they confuse writing with speech and believe they talk like they write. But spoken English is very different from what gets taught as "formal written English".

Comment: When I speak I use “they”, but when it comes to writing, I happen to be hesitating. Thank you very much for helping me! English is a very beautiful language

Comment: The issue here is that "the formal way" may vary from teacher to teacher. On my dissertation committee, I had one reader who loved singular "they" and one reader who marked up every instance and insisted on avoiding singular "they." (The third didn't care.) My gut feeling is that singular "they" is becoming accepted by more teachers and professors than it was even a decade ago, but gut feelings don't make good answers.

Answer (score 0):

[Discretion is the better part of valor.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discretion%20is%20the%20better%20part%20of%20valor)

> Someone forgot a hat. Make sure to find the owner.

Answer (score -2):

The following is the best choice:

> Someone forgot ***their*** hat.

Use of the possesive pronoun "***his***" in "someone forgot ***his*** hat" is archaic. If the person under discussion question could be be woman, then use somthing like "*they* forgot *their* hat"